# Searching ADSI using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

Good morning.  I’ve been trying to put together something on and off for days (that should be) simple using PS but I haven’t been able to figure it all out yet.  I am trying to search and retrieve information from ADSI using PS.  When I use the following in the PS console:

```
Get-ADObject "CN=OID,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com" -Properties *
```

It returns the object properties that have values assigned to them (which is correct) so that works.  But, what I need are children of the AD object, so I try to add *SearchScope*:

```
Get-ADObject "CN=OID,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com" -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties *
```

And I receive an error message reporting:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "CN=OID,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

So, I tried a different approach:

```
[string]$strCrLf = "`r`n"
[string]$strDoubleQuote = '"'
$ChildObjects = @()

$ParentObject = ([ADSI]"LDAP://CN=OID,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com")
ForEach ($Child in $ParentObject.psBase.Children)
    {
    $ChildObjects += @("([ADSI]" + $strDoubleQuote + $Child.Path + $strDoubleQuote + ").distinguishedName" + $strCrLf)
    }

$ChildObjects | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Expression $_
    }
```

The above does return the *distinguishedName* of the children, but how do I retrieve additional properties of the children, such as *displayName*, *Name* and *whenCreated*.  If I can get that, then I can work on putting it all into an array that can be exported to a CSV file or something.  Do I need to use something like LDAP instead?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-Filter` before the input string in your second example? You shouldn't need to, but worth trying if you're getting a positional parameter error. Also, wouldn't you want `Subtree` instead of `OneLevel` as a value for the `SearchScope` parameter to request all children?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `-Filter` but had the same error.  I only want one level returned for this one versus enumerating the tree, but good pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting you're doing in your first loop isn't really necessary. Try using the following:

```
$ChildItems = ([ADSI]"LDAP://CN=OID,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com")

$ChildItems.psbase.Children | Format-Table Name, DisplayName, whenCreated | Out-File C:\test.csv
```

Comment: AWESOME - works great.  Only one thing missing in your answer though (it should be `([ADSI]"LDAP://CN=OID` etc -- just add the _LDAP_ portion).  Thanks

Comment: Whoops, must have missed that in the copy/paste from my testing. I've updated the answer.